# How to implement sequential convoys in azure logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am new to azure logic apps.
Can any one help me how to implement sequential convoys in azure logic apps.

Comment: Is this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/send-related-messages-sequential-convoy) helpful to your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others coming across this, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/send-related-messages-sequential-convoy) as shared by @Hury in the comment on how you can implement sequential convoys in azure logic apps